# How to show success message alert on form submit in Sitecore 9 Forms in the same page?

Tags: sitecore-api, sitecore-forms, javascript

I am trying to implement a custom Sitecore 9 Forms (not WFFM forms) functionality. And I need to show a success alert message on successful submission of the form.

But here's the catch,

1. The success message should be available on the same page instead of going to next page as shown in ([How to show success message in Sitecore 9 Forms?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14834/how-to-show-success-message-in-sitecore-9-forms/14836)).
2. The submit button's "Navigation Step" should be "Submit", so that after we submit the form, the form should remain blank, with the success alert message on display at the top of the form.

The closest solution I could find was: https://citizensitecore.com/2017/12/13/sitecore-9-forms-and-ajax-with-sxa/.

But then, it uses form submit action callback in jquery, which gets triggered on submit and not success. Thus with forms having validation errors, the submit will still trigger.

So what are the possible solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute JavaScript on successful Form Submission](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24381/execute-javascript-on-successful-form-submission)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Sitecore Forms Extensions module: https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions

This includes a submit action to show a Form Page after submit. In this form page you can add the text you want and it will display in the same page and only after validation of the form (as it is a submit action).

If the module is not what you want, you can check the code on Github of the ShowFormPage submit action to create something custom that fits your needs.